# Change sudo and root password on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, root, password

I have sudo access, but I don't remember the sudo or root password; how do I change it from my limited account using sudo?

Answer (score 3):

The `sudo` password is *your* password; you only need `root`'s password if you're using `su` as non-`root`.

Comment: I am using a limited account

Comment: If, as your question implies, your limited account has `sudo` access, my answer still stands.

Answer (score 1):

As DopeGhoti mentions, `sudo` asks for your user password, not the root password.

If you have neither the root password nor the password of an account that has `sudo` rights, your next best bet is to reboot the server into maintenance mode, or if that doesn't work right, boot with `init=/bin/sh` as part of the kernel command line to change the root password.